# How to find the biggest number in accordance to the rules given (in a way of DP)?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Problem: Given a number `S` in the format of `abcdefijak...`, every letter refers to a digit. Every 3 digits compose of a 3-digital prime, each different from each other. What is the biggest possible `S`?

There are lots of method to solve the problem. What's my question is: how to solve it in DP?

Comment: The op asks for an algorithm

Comment: So just `abc` and `def` and so on need to be prime or also `bcd` and `cde`?

Comment: Isn't this a question for http://math.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @Stewart I don't think so. There is likely not much math in it, it is just a matter of trying all possibilities.

Comment: @Henry in the former case, the question is pretty trivial (and a huge number): Just sort descending all 3-digit primes and concatenate.

Comment: why does _a_ repeat a second time ? is it a typo or does it really appear twice ?

Comment: Your rules are not clear. Like @Henry said, what are the rules on primality? also, I have no idea how to continue the sequence `abcdefijak...`. Are only the 3-digit-groups required to be different, or may no two same digits occur within a distance of 3? Do you just want a list of all 3-digit-primes?

Comment: @JanDvorak right, thats why I am asking.

Comment: @Henry that's why I'm going to assume the latter

Comment: `k` is the 11th letter, which base is this?

Comment: @Stefan Base 10 of course. [Like everything](http://cowbirdsinlove.com/43).

Comment: -1 for posting a very ambiguous question and then not responding. note: this could have easily been a +1 if you have taken the effort to properly formulate the task.

Comment: If it is not said that digits must be different, they can be different or not. No ambiguity, +1.

Comment: @Gangnus there are lot of other ambiguities. Are the triples consecutive or overlapping, or even arbitrary triplets of digits? Does the term "three-digit prime" indeed imply that there must be no leading zero?

Comment: The last one seems absolutely definite to me. It is the DEFINITION of n-digit number. As for threes,... Hmm, yes, that could be read as every three digit combination should be prime. But I think, a question is enough, no need to punish for mislooking of very different understanding. If we, programmers, will be fined for ERRORS, we'll only pay for our work.

Comment: @Gangnus: just compare it with the duplicate. that's how you ask a question. no ambiguity there.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yes. But that one looks so AFTER 3 years of possible corrections. I have seen many questions that needed correction, but became good after it was done.

Comment: @Gangnus: you're wrong. again. if you check the history, the initial question is already perfectly clear.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Existance of questions that were well set from the beginning doesn't contradict with what I've said.

Comment: @Gangnus: The fact that you replied to my comment implies that you are referring to the ambiguity (just read the two comments sequentially. I don't see any other interpretation.).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36527/discussion-between-gangnus-and-karoly-horvath)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a stupid brute force algorithm:

```
def isprime(n):
    for x in xrange(2, int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    return True

primes3 = filter(isprime, range(100, 1000))

def biggest():
    return max([biggie(x, set(primes3)-set([x])) for x in primes3])

def biggie(sofar, primes):
    next2 = sofar % 100
    found = sofar
    for prime in filter(lambda x: 10*next2 <= x < 10*(next2+1), primes):
        found = max(found, biggie(10*sofar + (prime % 10), primes - set([prime])))
    return found
```

Which gave me the result of `9419919379773971911373313179`. Googled for it, and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836008/find-largest-number-with-all-contiguous-triples-being-unique-primes

Closing as duplicate...

Comment: Your result seems very strange to me. Why don't we start with 997? Why not 997991983977971967953947941937....?

Comment: just read the duplicate then you'll see the difference.

Comment: I see no answer neither there nor here. As for difference, yes, I see it. Just as I say - my number is bigger, so yours is wrong.

Comment: The format is `abcdefijak...`, not `abcdefghij...`.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath It's the right answer. How long will it take to caculate?

Comment: @Snowwolf would you please consider answering all the questions, and particularly the one about the digit ´a´ being duplicated ?

Comment: @Gangnus Let me rephrase - As per [the so-called duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836008/find-largest-number-with-all-contiguous-triples-being-unique-primes), every 3 consecutive numbers should be prime. 198, for example, isn't.

Comment: Maybe, but than it is really a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

Find all 3-digit primes and put them all one after another in descending order. If you have not unseen requirements in your task, that's all.